# Argument error in stratified sampling in R

Tags: r, error-handling, arguments, sampling

I need to use stratified sampling without replacement for the top 5 frequencies of the movie release years in data alltime.movies. The sample size is 1 from each of those 5 year groups. I have error in strata: all argument must be the same length, but I have no idea where the error comes from. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
library(sampling)
library(UsingR)
View(alltime.movies)

set.seed(489)
top_5 = head(sort(table(alltime.movies$Release.Year), decreasing = TRUE), n = 5)
dataset = subset(alltime.movies, alltime.movies$Release.Year%in%names(top_5))
dataset = dataset[order(dataset$Release.Year),]
dataset

st = strata(dataset, stratanames = c("Release.Year"), 
     size = rep(1,5), method = "srswor", description = TRUE)
```

Comment: Try writing `sampling::strata(...)`. It could be you're calling the wrong method.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. Is sampling::strata the name of the method? Why I cannot search it in R Help?

Comment: Sampling is the name of the package. By prefixing that to strata you ensure that you are using the method strata from the package sampling.

Comment: I loaded library(sampling), why I still need to specify sampling package? What's the difference between sampling::strata and strata? Is there any reference for that? Thank you so much.

Comment: That's because you could have multiple packages with the strata method, so by not specifying the package, R might think you are calling another package's strata method.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you so much.